# More efficient method to save 10 frames per second from a video between given timecode - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Ive got a set of videos, and a CSV file that with heading(start, end, category, season, episode) with the task to save 10 images per second between the start and end points in each row of the file. The method I devised (see below) first reads the CSV file and creates a list of integers (every 100 ms between the start and end points). Then using cv2 I load the video, go to the frame given in the list and progressively save each one.

My question in wether there is a quicker way to do this, whilst I havent done any speed tests or anything like that, the method just seems a bit slow and clunky. Any help appreciated.

```
import csv
import cv2

def readCSV():
    times = []
    reader = csv.DictReader(open("timecode.csv"))
    for i in reader:       
        l = range( ((int(str(i["start"])[0:2]))*60000) + 
                   ((int(str(i["start"])[2:4]))*1000), 

                   ((int(str(i["end"])[0:2]))*60000) + 
                   ((int(str(i["end"])[2:4]))*1000) )
        for j in l[::100]:
            times.append([i["season"], i["episode"], j, i["interaction"]])

    return times

def vid_to_frame(season, episode, timecode, category):
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture("s{}_e{}.mp4".format(str(season).zfill(2),
                                                str(episode).zfill(2)))
    vid.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, float(timecode))
    success, image = vid.read()
    if success:
        cv2.imwrite("E:/Hammond/readingVideos/imageSamples/{}/{}.jpg"
                    .format(str(category), str(timecode)), image)

for n in readCSV():
    vid_to_frame(n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3])
```

Comment: Do you need to save them as images or is it OK to save them as arrays ? If they are only an intermediate result that will require more processing in Python, you could consider saving them as Numpy arrays, which allows batch saving for more efficiency.

Comment: @Sunreef Nah, this is all the task I need the script to do, just output images, 10 a second, between a set of timecodes in a video. I wont be processing them afterwards, just a simple save an image.

Comment: Then you can try saving your images as BMP. This avoids the costly image compression algorithm when saving the image. It takes a lot of space on disk though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the video codec used, seeking to an exact time can be quite costly - up to the order of seconds - and is most likely what is the limiting factor here. You should profile your code to confirm this theory.

As you are extracting multiple consecutive frames it will be faster to open the video file once, seek to the first frame you want to extract, and then just keep decoding the file frame-by-frame. Write out the frames you are interested in, and just ignore the rest. Restructure your code to have only a single `VideoCapture` per file, and a single `set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, float(timecode))` per range of extracted frames.